# Android DrawerLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I'm trying to use the DrawerLayout with ActionBarDrawerToggle.
see my code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    FeedsFragment feeds = new FeedsFragment();

    if (findViewById(R.id.main) != null) {

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main, feeds).commit();

    } else if (findViewById(R.id.content) != null) {

        NavDrawerFragment nav = new NavDrawerFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.nav, nav)
                .add(R.id.content, feeds)
                .commit();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(config);
}
}
```

and my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--<include layout="@layout/nav" />-->
<fragment
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.primeirochute.com.primeirochute.fragment.NavDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/nav" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But when I run my project, the left menu (DrawerLayout) just show on my screen doesn't make the slider event.

Answer (score 3):

Finaly works:

I just added the gravity="start" at my second view

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--<include layout="@layout/nav" />-->
<fragment
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:name="com.primeirochute.com.primeirochute.fragment.NavDrawerFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/nav" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses the function [onOptionsItemSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) and control the drawer event:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemID = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemID) {
    case android.R.id.home: {
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }
        else {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    }
    break;
 return true;
}
```

I hope it works for your case.